# how set path to property file in jave

Tags: java, properties

I want use property file in my java project. I put this fie in src/main/resources/application.properties. Then in code I have:

```
public static String loadProperty(String name)
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(PropertyLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
    ...
```

But got error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
at com.tests.util.PropertyLoader.loadProperty(PropertyLoader.java:23)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `proj.properties` is not `application.properties` !

Comment: the file name is `proj.properties` and you're trying to load the `application.properties`

Comment: Sorry, it is just a typo, problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Check the file name. Is it proj.properties or application.properties